# How do I input SSML in Google TTS? (C#)

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I have been using the sample C# code provided by Google to familiarise myself with Google TTS. I want to input ssml, but I can't work out how to do this. If someone could tell me what line(s) of code I need to change, then I would be very grateful.

I tried changing 'Text' to 'SSML' below but this didn't work. I also tried using SSML tags in the inputted text and this didn't work either.

I have looked through the relevant Google SSML documentation, but I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

```
using Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace TextToSpeechApiDemo
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = TextToSpeechClient.Create();

        // The input to be synthesized, can be provided as text or SSML.
        var input = new SynthesisInput
        {
            Text = "This is a demonstration of the Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API"
        };

        // Build the voice request.
        var voiceSelection = new VoiceSelectionParams
        {
            LanguageCode = "en-US",
            SsmlGender = SsmlVoiceGender.Female
        };

        // Specify the type of audio file.
        var audioConfig = new AudioConfig
        {
            AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Mp3
        };

        // Perform the text-to-speech request.
        var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(input, voiceSelection, audioConfig);

        // Write the response to the output file.
        using (var output = File.Create("output.mp3"))
        {
            response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Audio content written to file \"output.mp3\"");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is very easy. Change your section of code:

```
var input = new SynthesisInput
{
    Text = "This is a demonstration of the Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API"
};
```

To this:

```
var input = new SynthesisInput
{
    Ssml = "<speak>This is a demonstration of the Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API.<break time=\"1s\"/>This API is very easy to use.<break time=\"1s\"/><say-as interpret-as=\"characters\">SSML</say-as>is also easy to use.</speak>"
};
```

[Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML)](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for providing an answer to this John, I can confirm that it works.